# How do I copy and paste a table in a dynamic cell reference and name it in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm relatively new to VBA (Using Excel 2019). I've got a dynamic table (always starts from the same cell but can have different number of columns and rows). What I'm trying to do is copy and paste that table a couple of rows below it, name it to to something I can reference in later code and then strip the values from the pasted table.

Currently I'm doing this (I haven't attempted stripping the values out yet):

```
Dim cellRef As String
Range("Table3[#All]").Copy
Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2).Select
Set cellRef = Selection
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ActiveCell").Name = "Table4"
```

My current thinking is that I know that line number 3 works and selects the cell I want to paste my table into. So before I paste it I can save it down as a cell reference then I can re-select that cell and name it to table4. I'm also thinking that then I can reference Table 4 and (hopefully) there's a command that selects all the data values in the table (so not the headers and columns) which I can then delete and re-format to numbers from percentages which they are currently in.

The current code gives a 'Subscript out of Range' error message on the last line. Any help would be massively appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Use `Activecell.ListObject` instead of `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ActiveCell")`

Comment: You can directly set range variables without using `Select` or `Selection`. Generally, avoiding `Select` will improve your code in speed and reliability, as well as making it easier to understand and edit when the script starts getting longer. `Set cellRef = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2)`

Comment: To avoid using the windows clipboard, I suggest using the `Destination` argument of `.Copy`. This is dramatically faster, and avoids entering `CutCopyMode`, which might mess things up later if not handled properly. How to do it: `SourceRange.Copy Destination:=TargetRange`

Comment: You have declared `cellRef` as a `String` when it needs to be a `Range`

Comment: To get the Range associated with a ListObjects data, not including the headers or total row, use `ListObject.DataBodyRange`.

Comment: Thank you @Toddleson ! I've now go this code which successfully will rename the table:

Dim cellRef  As Range
    Range("Table3[#All]").Copy
    Set cellRef = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(4)
    ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.ListObject.Name = "Table4"

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting - very new to stack overflow as well!

Comment: If you just want to change the display format of some values, you don't need to delete and rewrite them. You can change the `NumberFormat` and the value will automatically update how it is displayed. Try something like `Activesheet.ListObjects("Table4").ListColumns(#).DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "0"` where # is the column number for those values you want to change.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do the destination argument you mention. My current attempt is:

SourceRange ("Table3[#All]").Copy
Set cellRef = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(4)
    Destination = ActiveSheet.Paste

But I can tell this is way off! Could you provide any clarification on what I'm doing wrong.

Also when I try to delete the data body range this is throwing me an error message also:
ListObject.DataBodyRange.Delete

Think I need ot add a range somewhere? Not sure

Comment: `Set cellRef = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2)`  and then `Range("Table3[#All]").Copy Destination:=cellRef`

Comment: Since you're eliminating `Select`, the application wont be updating `Activecell` during your code. I suggest also eliminating the use of `Activecell` and doing `cellRef.ListObject.Name` instead of using `Activecell.ListObject.Name`.

Comment: Thank you so much again - got the destination pasting working now. I'm trying to do both actually - change the format and delete the values (there's one percentage table and one number table. I'm pasting the percentage table and then going to times the percentage cell to the matching number cell in the other table) .

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table4").ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "0"

This code isn't giving me an error but isn't changing the format. I don't know if column 4 is right? (did it because the table starts in column D). Also don't know if I can incorporate delete?

Comment: The listcolumn # is relative to the table's position. So `ListColumns(1)` will be the table's first column, no matter where the table is.

Comment: To clear the data from a listobject or listcolumn you can do `.DataBodyRange.ClearContents`. If you want to remove a row from the table, you can do `Activesheet.ListObjects("Table4").ListRows(#).Delete` where # is the row number you want to remove.